# Qt Designer: extend internal search path with environment variables?

Tags: python, qt, environment-variables, designer, qt-designer

I am trying to integrate the Qt Designer into my CG-Pipeline and have the Designer already extended with custom widget plugins (python).
I would like to extend some other paths as well, preferred with the help of environment variables.

What environment variables doe the Qt Designer accepts/supports?

And is it possible to change the templates path to a network location with an environment variable?